# CSS background on text issue

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm creating a horizontal menu with an effect on user hover. When the user hovers over a link it would create a red background that is a bit bigger than the menu banner itself.

I have this to illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/65466g17/

I tried using padding and a margin, but no avail. Is there some other alternative for this scenario?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-outer">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MONITORING</a></li>
            <li><div id="imgBox"><a href="#"></a></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-outer {          
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.6);
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    width:100%;    
    min-width: 1200px;
    max-height: 60px;        
}

#menu {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center; 
    justify-content: center;                
    font-family: "Menu Font", "Info Box",Verdana;
    font-weight: 800;    
    font-size:medium; 


}

ul#horizontal-list {       
    list-style: none;
    padding:0; 

}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline-block;    
}

#menu a{
    text-decoration:none;       
    float:left;    
    color:black;
    padding:2px 15px;    
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#menu a:hover{ 
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    padding:30px 5px;
    margin-top: -28px;       
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Should the menu grow? Should the background shrink?

Comment: It seems to be working for me, on my iPad atm.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/65466g17/2/ Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/65466g17/3/

Comment: @HashemQolami post it as an answer and give some explanation if possible.

Comment: @LeonelMachava Thanks for your suggestion. Just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen, increasing the `height` or adding `padding`/`margin` to the hovered link may affect the layout.

Instead, we can use `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements to achieve the desired effect. It can be done by positioning the pseudo-element `absolute`ly and playing with `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` offsets as follows:

```css
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;       
    float:left;    
    color:black;
    padding:1em;    
    white-space:nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#menu a:hover:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -.5em;
    bottom: -.5em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background:red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Note that in this case, `a` elements MUST have a `position` of `relative` (anything other than `static`) to establish a containing block for absolutely positioned pseudo-elements.

Also, adding `z-index: -1` to our pseudo-elements make them appear behind the contents of the links.

```css
#menu-outer {          
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.6);
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  width:100%;    
  min-width: 1200px;
  max-height: 60px;        
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center; 
  justify-content: center;                
  font-family: "Menu Font", "Info Box",Verdana;
  font-weight: 800;    
  font-size:medium; 


}

ul#horizontal-list {       
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline-block;    
}

#menu a{
  text-decoration:none;       
  float:left;    
  color:black;
  padding:1em;    
  white-space:nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu a:hover:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.5em;
  bottom: -.5em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-outer">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="horizontal-list">
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MONITORING</a></li>
      <li><div id="imgBox"><a href="#"></a></div></li>
      <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your fiddle giving an absolute positioning to  `#menu a:hover`,

take a look http://jsfiddle.net/maio/65466g17/5/,

`position: absolute` takes the element out of the document flow so it won't affect any other element

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky to get negative margins working with lists. How about a nice transform?

```
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: transform 0.3s; /* adjust transform duration here */
}
#menu a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* adjust transform size here */
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* adjust transform size here */
    transform: scale(1.2); /* adjust transform size here */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/65466g17/7)**